# Convert user-defined function to stored procedure for EF

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

This is my user-defined function used in a project:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Encrypt]
(
@Password nvarchar(4000)
)
RETURNS varbinary(4000)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @Password = CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),@Password);
RETURN HashBytes('SHA1', @Password);
END
GO
```

I need Entity Framework so, it's possible find a way to convert this one in a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Procedure Definition**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Encrypt]
@Password   nvarchar(4000), 
@HashedPass varbinary(4000) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
   SET @HashedPass = HashBytes('SHA1',CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),@Password));
END
```

**EXECUTE PROCEDURE**

```
DECLARE @RtnHashedPass varbinary(4000);

EXECUTE [dbo].[usp_Encrypt]
@Password   = 'myPassword'
@HashedPass = @RtnHashedPass OUTPUT

SELECT @RtnHashedPass  --<-- Do what ever you want to do with this value
```

Comment: Well. I've created the stored procedure using your procedure definition, is it right? So, how can I do the execute procedure?

Comment: Yes it is correct if you read the second section in my answer I have explained how you can execute this procedure.

Comment: Just one question. The original function returned varbinary, but the new one returns nvarchar. Is it an error or not? Because in my old db the password value was in varbinary.